# how to create Materialized view for a existing table in delta live table in Databricks using pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

Here I am trying to create a materialized view for existing Delta Live Table using pyspark, I tried many times but it shows error every time. Can we create materialized view in DLT?, If so please share the resource? Thank you!

Comment: What is the use case for that? Change table structure, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot create materialized view for delta live table, because the delta live table does the same. Instead we can create view in delta live table

Comment: you can accept your own answer using that green check mark